# Find the index by current sort order of an array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

If there is an array

```
array A = ["a","b","c","d"] #Index is [0,1,2,3]
```

And it's sorted to.

```
array A = ["d","c","b","a"]
```

I need an array that returns me the updated index based on the sorted order

```
[3,2,1,0]
```

I'm trying to find a solution to this ruby

**UPDATE to the question**

If a is sorted to

```
array A = ["d","b","c","a"] #not a pure reverse
```

Then the returned index array should be

```
[3,1,2,0]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[ask]". We'd like to see your effort toward solving the problem. Did you write code? If so, read "[mcve]". We don't write code for you, but we do help you fix your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a mapping table that preserves the original order, then use that order to un-map the re-ordered version:

```
orig = %w[ a b c d ]
orig_order = orig.each_with_index.to_h

revised = %w[ d c b a ]

revised.map { |e| orig_order[e] }
# => [3, 2, 1, 0]
```

So long as your elements are unique this will be able to track any shift in order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` and `index` methods.

```
arr = ["a","b","c","d"]

sort_arr = ["d","c","b","a"]

sort_arr.map{|s| arr.index(s)}
# => [3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Good simple solution, but could get out of hand performance-wise if the array gets large. What happens if there is a duplicated element in the array, and what is the desired behavior?

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz Yes, it could be performace problems if the array gets large, in this case i will recoment to use some `Hash` way. Duplicated elements will be problem, but the Answer don't specify the behaviour in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this:

```
original_array = ["a","b","c","d"]
jumbled_array = original_array.shuffle

jumbled_array.map {|i| original_array.index(i)}
#=> [1, 3, 0, 2]
```

**Note:**

1. In this sample, output will change for every run as we are using `shuffle` to demonstrate the solution.
2. The solution will work only as long as array has no duplicate values.

---

If you do wish to solution to work with arrays with duplicate values, then, one possibility is to look at `object_id` of array members while figuring out the index.

```
jumbled_array.map {|i| original_array.map(&:object_id).index(i.object_id)}
```

This solution will work as long as `jumbled_array` contains element from `original_array` and no elements were recreated using `dup` or something that results in change in `object_id` values